# Inquiry of Drake simulator automatic differentiation

Tags: drake

I have a question regarding the drake simulator's automatic differentiation abilities. I have a paper coming out soon in a few months and some of the feedback was that I didn't comment enough on automatic differentiation.

I am familiar with automatic differentiation but am unclear how it works with physics simulators exactly.As far as i'm aware, once you have constructed the graph, you can query it several times with a forwards pass and calculate the partial derivatives of outputs with respect to inputs. In my head, querying such a graph should be computationally quick.

In the drake simulator, once I load a scene, lets say a robot arm with a single free body item (like a cube or cylinder), does it create a graph that you can query regardless of the state of the system? Or does the graph need to be reconstructed depending on the system state. For instance would the same graph work in a situation when the arm was in contact with the free body item and also when it is doing free space motion?

There is this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2202.13986.pdf) where they use drake for contact based manipulation tasks in python. Their optimization takes significant time and they claim it is down to drakes automatic differentiation scheme. The only way I can think getting the derivatives over their trajectories takes so long is if at each time step, a new graph needs to be constructed.

Is anyone able to comment on this from the drake team? Or maybe even link me a useful document regarding how drake's automatic differentiation works? I have been unsuccessful in finding this information myself so far.

Answer (score 0):

Drake uses Eigen's [AutoDiffScalar](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/classEigen_1_1AutoDiffScalar.html) instead of `double` to obtain derivatives from the same code we use for computation. That method does not build a graph at all but rather performs rote propagation of the chain rule though the computation, ending up finally with both the result and partial derivatives of that result with respect to any chosen variables.